# Not being able to build emergent

Tags: c, linux, cmake, compilation, arch

I need to run this software as part of my CS course but I have no idea how to proceed further with this build.
emergent: https://github.com/emer/cemer
I run Arch Linux and whilst their is a package for it in the AUR alas it doesn't work: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/emergent/

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/emergent/
```

then i cd inside of it and run

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --bindir=~/.scripts/emergent2 --libdir=/usr/lib --qt5
```

```
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- ********************* Summary of Key Build Parameters *************************
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = /usr
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = RelWithDebInfo
--       (Options are: Debug | Release | RelWithDebInfo | MinSizeRel)
-- MPI_BUILD = FALSE   (true or false)
-- 
-- Change a value with: cmake -D<Variable>=<Value>
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- ********************* Summary of Prerequisities  ******************************
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- QT_LIBRARIES = Qt5::Core;Qt5::Gui;Qt5::Widgets;Qt5::OpenGL;Qt5::Xml;Qt5::Network;Qt5::PrintSupport;Qt5::Multimedia;Qt5::Svg
-- COIN_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/libCoin.so
-- GSL_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libgsl.so;/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so
-- ODE_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/libode.so
-- OPENGL_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libGL.so;/usr/lib/libGLU.so
-- ZLIB_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libz.so
-- SUBVERSION_LIBRARIES = /lib/libsvn_client-1.so;/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so;/lib/libsvn_fs-1.so;/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so;/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so;/lib/libsvn_ra-1.so;/usr/lib/libapr-1.so;/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so;/lib/libsvn_client-1.so;/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so;/lib/libsvn_fs-1.so;/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so;/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so;/lib/libsvn_ra-1.so;/usr/lib/libapr-1.so;/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so
-- READLINE_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/libreadline.so
-- optional libraries = /usr/lib/libsndfile.so
-- all EMERGENT_DEP_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libCoin.so;Qt5::Core;Qt5::Gui;Qt5::Widgets;Qt5::OpenGL;Qt5::Xml;Qt5::Network;Qt5::PrintSupport;Qt5::Multimedia;Qt5::Svg;/usr/lib/libode.so;/usr/lib/libgsl.so;/usr/lib/libGL.so;/usr/lib/libGLU.so;/usr/lib/libz.so;/lib/libsvn_client-1.so;/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so;/lib/libsvn_fs-1.so;/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so;/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so;/lib/libsvn_ra-1.so;/usr/lib/libapr-1.so;/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so;/lib/libsvn_client-1.so;/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so;/lib/libsvn_fs-1.so;/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so;/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so;/lib/libsvn_ra-1.so;/usr/lib/libapr-1.so;/usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so;/usr/lib/libsndfile.so;/usr/lib/libreadline.so;/usr/lib/libreadline.so;TERMCAP_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Can not find dpkg in your path, default to i386.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CPack.cmake:561 (message):
  CPack package description file: "/home/ivan/.scripts/cemer/README.txt"
  could not be found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CPack.cmake:565 (cpack_check_file_exists)
  CMakeModules/EmergentCPack.cmake:131 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:349 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ivan/.scripts/cemer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 
####################################################
Now you must type: cd build; make; make install
to actually build and install the software
```

I have tried all the build .sh files with no avail.

any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: You should ask the package maintainer

Comment: Already done that, he has relinquished control of the package and ceased maintaining it